# "Save as type" not showing up

Tags: vb.net

Ok so I am trying to save a file and I want to limit the user to a couple options being *.txt and *.*. I want to make the default *.txt. The code works to save the file, but I don't see the "save as type" option as having any choices and the default .txt extension is not in the file name field. What am I missing or doing wrong?

```
Private Sub SaveFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles SaveFileDialog1.FileOk
    'Write the converted string to the file
    Dim FileToSaveAs As String = SaveFileDialog1.FileName

    Dim FileWriter As New StreamWriter(FileToSaveAs)
    With SaveFileDialog1
        .DefaultExt = ".txt"
        .FilterIndex = 2
        .RestoreDirectory = True
        .Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        .InitialDirectory = "C:\AppTemp"
        .Title = "Save processed file"
    End With

    FileWriter.Write(TextOut)
    FileWriter.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Where's your call to ShowDialog()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set SaveFileDialog params before you show it.
Try this:

```
public sub SaveFile
    With SaveFileDialog1
        .DefaultExt = ".txt"
        .FilterIndex = 1
        .RestoreDirectory = True
        .Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        .InitialDirectory = "C:\AppTemp"
        .Title = "Save processed file"
        If .ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK then
            Dim FileWriter As New StreamWriter(.Filename)
            FileWriter.Write(TextOut)
            FileWriter.Close()
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Tharkis: sorry, which is your problem with this? Explain better (please) and I'll help you

Comment: Turns out if I put the code in the button click event, I am able to see the save as type. I think that was my problem. Thanks for leading me in the right direction.